# Are the filtering problem and decoding problem the same thing?

Tags: sequence, markov-hidden-model, kalman-filter

Is there any distinction the filtering problem and the decoding problem?
Wikipedia's definition for a filtering problem is:
The problem of estimating the states or ideally the posterior distribution of the states of a dynamical systems where only partial observations are made, and random perturbations are present. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtering_problem_(stochastic_processes)
While the definition of the decoding problem from Stanford Lectures is:
Given an observation sequence O and an HMM λ = (A, B), discover the best hidden state sequence Q.
[https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/A.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/A.pdf)
In my view, these two definitions are describing the same problem. Am I correct or did I miss something?